# Input textbox value not updating database table

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a asp.net webform and I am creating an update profile page. I am testing the connection to the DB by giving a specific user to pull from the user table. The user data does pop up in the  textbox but when I change the text and click the save button the data is not updated. All SQL Queries are stored procedures.

C# Code:

```
    protected void EditProfileBtn_Clicked(object obj, EventArgs args)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection_string_Is_Here);

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("EditProfile_sp", con);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", userID);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", FirstNametbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", LastNametbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Country", Countrytbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("State", Statetbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", Citytbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", Emailtbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", Phonetbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("MyInterest", MyInteresttbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("MySkills", MySkillstbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("MyRoles", MyRolestbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("MyAvailability", MyAvailtbx.Value);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx");
            
        }
    }
```

Stored Procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EditProfile_sp] (

    @UserID int, 
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @LastName varchar(50),
    @Country varchar(50),
    @State varchar(50),
    @City varchar(50),
    @Email varchar(50),
    @MyInterest varchar(50),
    @MySkills varchar(50),
    @MyRoles varchar(50),
    @MyAvailability varchar(50),
    @Phone varchar(20)

)

AS 

BEGIN

 UPDATE PESAUser 

              SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName,
              Country = @Country, [State] = @State, 
              City = @City, Email = @Email, MyInterest = @MyInterest, MySkills = @MySkills, MyRole = @MyRoles,
              MyAvailability = @MyAvailability, Phone = @Phone 
              WHERE UserID = @UserID
END
```

There are no thrown exceptions to this code the issue is that there is no updating to the database table. All spelling issues have been checked.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer that represents the number of rows updated. Can you catch this return value and tell us what number do you get?

Comment: @Steve the return value is 1

Comment: So the code has updated a record. Are you sure that you are checking the same database that you are working with? What is your connection string?

Comment: Please read Joel Coehoorn's [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and Dan Guzman's [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Also make sure you aren't using `AttachDbFileName` in your C# connection string and explain exactly how you are checking that "the data is not updated."

Comment: My page_load() does have a procedure to pull the current data within the user table. This doesn't seem like an issue to me since I can change the values in the input boxes while the page isn't being refreshed and take the current values and update it to the table with the respective User ID.

Comment: Connection String:                                                                                                  
 @"Data Source=DESKTOP-9TVHNCS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PESA DB;Integrated Security=True"

Answer (score 0):

For textboxes in web land? You use the .text, and not .value

And ALSO VERY imporant:

You only want to load + bind in the !IsPostBack on page load.

Remember, when you click a button, or do ANYTHING on that page?

The page load event will fire each time, and THEN your code stub. So, if you load up text boxes, or even say a dropdown list? If you re-load on page load, then all the values are re-loaded, and you lose all your changes.

So, say we have text box First name, and Last name.

Markup:

```
     FirstName:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
         LastName:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" cssclass="btn"/>
        <br />
```

Ok, our page load, and page save code is thus this:

So the minimal code looks like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["RecNum"] = 19;
            LoadMyData();
        }
    }

    void LoadMyData()
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE ID = @ID");
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ViewState["RecNum"];

        DataRow OneRow = MyRstP(cmdSQL).Rows[0];
        txtFirst.Text = OneRow["FirstName"].ToString();
        txtLast.Text = OneRow["LastName"].ToString();
    }

    protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSQL = 
            "UPDATE tblHotels SET FirstName = @First," +
            "LastName = @Last WHERE ID = @ID";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ViewState["RecNum"];
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFirst.Text;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Last", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLast.Text;

        MyRstP(cmdSQL, true);

    }

    public DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL, bool ExecuteOnly = false)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                if (ExecuteOnly)
                    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
                else
                    rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

Most imporant tip in ALL OF above?

Note how we ONLY load the data ONE time on !IsPostBack (false).

If we don't do above, then we wind up re-loading all data again, and thus our changes are never seen.

Remember:

Page load fires each and every time - so a button click, a autopost back for a drop down list - they all will fire page load AGAIN!!!!

And if in page load, we re-load our data, then that data re-loads, and THEN your button code stub runs.

So, we have this:

[image]